# How can I paste code to anywhere from Free Pascal IDE?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm working on Free Pascal IDE. When I want to share my Pascal code, I run into a problem. I can't paste code that I copy to anywhere. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pastie](http://pastie.org/) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/). That's the first that comes to mind.

Comment: i am not searching for code pasting platform, the problem is "i can't paste any codes which copied from free pascal ide".

Comment: Are they actually copied? Try to use menu, instead of hotkeys (maybe they are not standart). Or you can open source file in another editor and copy from it.. What OS, FPC IDE are you using?

Comment: Understand you. In my Windows FPC IDE there is a menu item `Copy to Windows`. Use it to copy to windows clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

And what about using another IDE?
I've just started to use a text editor/IDE multilanguage called Geany and it's way better than free pascal.
Give it a try, maybe you will have to configure it first but then when you have all set is a powerful tool, and you can add themes or modify colors/text type/etc.